# Error with checking for neighbors in 2d array

Tags: haskell

I am attempting to implement Conway's game in Haskell for class and have code that looks like this for checking for neighbors of a cell (x,y) in a square board of size (w,h):

```
liveNeighbors :: ((Int,Int), [[Bool]]) -> (Int,Int) -> Int
liveNeighbors arr@((w,h), cells) (x,y) =
    let
        j = w -1
        k = h - 1
        checkcell (x,y) = if (cells !! y) !! x then 1 else 0 in
    case (x,y) of
    -- Check right, bottom, and bottom right
    (0,0) -> checkcell (x,y+1) + checkcell (x+1,y) + checkcell (x+1,y+1)
    -- Check bottom, left, right, bottom left, bottom right
    (_,0) -> checkcell (x,y+1) + checkcell (x-1,y) + checkcell (x+1,y)
             + checkcell (x+1,y+1)  + checkcell (x-1,y+1)
    -- check bottom, top, right, top right, bottom right
    (0,_) -> checkcell (x,y+1)  + checkcell (x,y-1)  + checkcell (x+1,y)
             + checkcell (x+1,y+1)  + checkcell (x+1,y-1)
    -- check top, left, right,top left, top right
    (_, k) -> checkcell (x,y-1)  + checkcell (x-1,y)  + checkcell (x+1,y)
             + checkcell (x-1,y-1)  + checkcell (x+1,y-1)
    -- check bottom, top, left, top left, bottom left
    (j, _) -> checkcell (x,y+1)  + checkcell (x,y-1)  + checkcell (x-1,y)
             + checkcell (x-1,y+1)  + checkcell (x-1,y-1)
    -- check top, left, top left
    (j,k) -> checkcell (x,y-1)  + checkcell (x-1,y)  + checkcell (x-1,y-1)
    -- check bottom, left, bottom left
    (j,0) -> checkcell (x,y+1)  + checkcell (x-1,y)  + checkcell (x-1,y+1)
    -- check top, top right, right
    (0,k) -> checkcell (x,y-1)  + checkcell (x+1,y-1)  + checkcell (x+1,y)
    -- check all surrounding
    (_,_) -> checkcell (x,y+1)  + checkcell (x,y-1)  + checkcell (x+1,y)
             + checkcell (x-1,y)  + checkcell (x+1,y+1) + checkcell (x+1,y-1)
             + checkcell (x-1,y+1)  + checkcell (x-1,y-1)
```

I am using `j` and `k` to fit for the bounds of the array. I am checking for all edge cases, and corners however the code is failing for array sizes and rows at  `(_, max_row)`, `(max_column, _)`, `(max_column, max_row)` and giving incorrect values. This is the output that ghci is giving me:

```
> world = ((3,3), [[False, False, False], [False, False, False], [False, True,True]])
> liveNeighbors world (2,2)
*** Exception: Prelude.!!: index too large
> liveNeighbors world (0,2)
*** Exception: Prelude.!!: index too large
> liveNeighbors world (0,1)
1
> liveNeighbors world (1,1)
0
```

The value for `(1,1)` should give 2 since the bottom and bottom right are true, however it is only giving a value of 1. Any idea why this is happening?

**I'm not looking for a code solution, if someone could point me in the right direction conceptually on what is going wrong that would be greatly appreciated.** This is for a project confining to list processing so no other data structures other than lists or tuples are allowed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 2 problems in this code:

1. **order of patterns**: in your example you get error message when test your code for `(2,2)` position. It is because pattern `(_, k)` goes earlier than `(j, k)`, so you check "top, left, right,top left, top right", not "top, left, top left" as you expected
2. **variables in patterns**: pattern `(_, k)` match successfully with other values of `(x, y)` in your code and patterns below it are overlapped. You just assign `k` to `y`, not compare them

So, you can write code like this (I use `MultiWayIf` extension for more similarity with original, but it is just syntax sugar):

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE MultiWayIf #-}

neighbors :: ((Int,Int), [[Bool]]) -> (Int,Int) -> Int
neighbors arr@((w,h), cells) (x,y) = 
    let 
        j = w -1
        k = h - 1 
        checkcell (x,y) = if (cells !! y) !! x then 1 else 0 in 
    if
        -- Check right, bottom, and bottom right
        | (x, y) == (0,0) -> checkcell (x,y+1) + checkcell (x+1,y) + checkcell (x+1,y+1)
        --check top, left, top left
        | (x, y) == (j,k) -> checkcell (x,y-1)  + checkcell (x-1,y)  + checkcell (x-1,y-1) 
        --check bottom, left, bottom left
        | (x, y) == (j,0) -> checkcell (x,y+1)  + checkcell (x-1,y)  + checkcell (x-1,y+1) 
        -- check top, top right, right
        | (x, y) == (0,k) -> checkcell (x,y-1)  + checkcell (x+1,y-1)  + checkcell (x+1,y) 
        -- Check bottom, left, right, bottom left, bottom right
        | y == 0 -> checkcell (x,y+1) + checkcell (x-1,y) + checkcell (x+1,y)  + checkcell (x+1,y+1)  + checkcell (x-1,y+1) 
        --check bottom, top, right, top right, bottom right
        | x == 0 -> checkcell (x,y+1)  + checkcell (x,y-1)  + checkcell (x+1,y)  + checkcell (x+1,y+1)  + checkcell (x+1,y-1) 
        -- check top, left, right,top left, top right
        | y == k -> checkcell (x,y-1)  + checkcell (x-1,y)  + checkcell (x+1,y)  + checkcell (x-1,y-1)  + checkcell (x+1,y-1) 
        -- check bottom, top, left, top left, bottom left
        | x == j -> checkcell (x,y+1)  + checkcell (x,y-1)  + checkcell (x-1,y)  + checkcell (x-1,y+1)  + checkcell (x-1,y-1) 
        --check all surrounding 
        | otherwise -> checkcell (x,y+1)  + checkcell (x,y-1)  + checkcell (x+1,y)  + checkcell (x-1,y)  + checkcell (x+1,y+1)  +checkcell (x+1,y-1)  + checkcell (x-1,y+1)  + checkcell (x-1,y-1)
```